# How to install Telegram-messenger on Puppy Linux?

Tags: software-installation, puppy-linux

I want to install Telegram-messenger (latest version) on Puppy Linux.

How to solve this question?

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Telegram messenger works straight away on Linux systems without need of installation or any specific configuration.

Just download the archive from its official site and extract it. Run Telegram binary and login to your account. It'll keep running in background. You can also add it in your profile file to start it with your login.

Answer (score 0):

Click here and it will start downloading .deb package & double click after downloading it will get installed in puppy linux automatically.
[Telegram for Puppy Linux](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/telegram-desktop/telegram-desktop_1.2.17-1_amd64.deb)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the correct answer that Vishakha has given you, there are some archives .pet with Telegram, the only problem is that the version doesn't go with the oficial aplication. So if you have an old computer with few memory and space I recomend you that version. If you have a computer with 1 giga or more the oficial version is ok.
Here the pet archive: http://oldforum.puppylinux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?search_id=1162328567&t=112133&sid=772762e6ef62bfb01324db2496d49894, Maybe if you look up in this forum you would find a modern version. See you